# Этимология слова «даже» / Etymology of the word “dazhe” (even, although)

Tags: этимология, психолингвистика

Каково происхождение слова? Сочетание *да* + *же* представляется слишком очевидным. Фасмер дает только ****датже***, не останавливаясь на использовании современной лексемы и не останавливаясь на элизии (маловероятной). Есть ли другие источники?

---

What is the origin of the word? The combination of *да* + *же* seems too obvious. Vasmer provides the only example of ****датже*** without detailed explanation of its origin, nor the elision is explained. Are there any other sources?

Comment: Вы у Фасмера где нашли? В издании 1986 слова _даже_ в принципе нет.

Comment: В какой-то другой статье примечанием. Дело давнее. В любом случае, интерес к Фасмеру и к этому сайту у меня существенно уменьшился после "общения" с большинством местных пользователей.

Comment: Если найдёте, где увидели, отпишитесь, а то _датже_ даже гугль не находит.

Comment: И всё ж ступайте в гугл или перечитайте Фасмера. Точность формулировок, терминология, библиография и прочие мелочи = чужая мне печаль.

Comment: Повторяю: _датже_ [гугль не находит](https://www.google.com/#hl=ru&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=датже+фасмер&oq=датже+фасмер&gs_l=hp.3...4376.9003.0.9859.12.12.0.0.0.0.192.1347.6j6.12.0...0.0...1c.1.M16z2sKvq6I&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.cGE&fp=f27c55883a594903&biw=1600&bih=756).

Comment: `да`+`же` наименее вероятное происхождение. скорее родственно `дать`.

Answer (score 2):

По Шанскому (*Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов*, 2004, у Крылова (2008) также):

> **ДАЖЕ** Искон. Сращение частиц *да* и *же*. Ср. *аж*

Сравниваем *аж*:

> **АЖ**. Искон. Сращение союза *а* «и, да» и частицы *же*. Конечный безударный *е* отпал так же, как и в *авось*.

У Фасмера *даже* упоминается здесь:

> **да** — нареч., союз, *да́бы*, *да́же*;

Фасмер также указывает на сращение в словах *аж* и *уже*, *уж*. Т. е., похоже, что это достаточно обычное явление.

Comment: Сращение это, конечно, хорошо, а какой именно путь привёл к нынешнему значению этого слова? Без описания такого пути такое описание этимологии не стоит ничего...

Comment: Опасная привычка наблюдается, придумывать этимологию по созвучию. А ведь сколько чудесных дисциплин в лингвистике.